# Launching an HTML file locally?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am new to web development. I use Brackets to do my development in. My webpage works using the live preview in Brackets but when I launch the page outside of Brackets, my JS doesn't load.

What I am asking is, is there a way to launch a webpage (HTML, CSS, JS) without creating a server for it all?

Comment: "my JS doesn't load" is too vague a description of the problem. It could be just a case of paths being wrong. It could be that you are trying to do something forbidden on a local drive. Trying to do web development without a web server is usually more trouble than it is worth though.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the html file in your file system. Right click and open it in a browser of your choice.

Right now, it seems like clicking that file will open it in Brackets for you, however html files are able to be rendered by browsers when they read the html code.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I had a typo in my script link.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, just put your HTML/CSS/JS in the same location — or different locations — and make sure you map to them properly.

From there, just double click your index.html — or whatever you named your html file — and it should popup in your browser.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I had a typo in my script link.